# How to map between logstash extracted fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am extracting info from logfiles, but I want to map them together for aggregations, here's a sample logfile:

```
2017-01-01 07:53:44 [monitor_utils.py] INFO: Crawled iteration for merchant ariika started
2017-01-01 07:53:44 [utils.py] INFO: UpdateCrawlIteration._start_crawl_iteration function took 0.127 s
2017-01-01 07:57:22 [statscollectors.py] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'item_scraped_count': 22,
 'invalid_items_count': 84}
```

I am extracting the merchant name from  the first line `ariika` and `items_scraped_counts, invalid_items_count` from the last two lines, I have different logfiles for each merchant, and I want to know items scraped count per logfile for each merchant using Kibana.

How to filter between one merchant and another in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you in a correct way, I believe the **source field** in kibana can help you. 
The source field indicates the name of log file.

using the **bar char**, you can choose the metric that you want based in your **tems scraped count field**, and then create a bucket aggregation using the **source field**. And filter based in **merchant field** in the **kibana search bar**.

Or on top of the first aggregation you can create another aggregation using the **merchant field** and choose the split bars. without using the kibana search bar.